# How to delete the intermediate files generated during EMMA in ant

Tags: ant, emma

I have an ant task of emma which generates the code coverage report in HTML. So far so good. But I see intermediate files being generated . Now I need to delete this .Though I have given the task emma clean , I am unable to delete folder which has the name like ${instr.dir.out}. This folder is created in all the components and I am clueless as how can I delete them.

Answer (score 2):

All my ANT builds have a standard "clean" target, designed to clean up any any files or directories created by the build:

```
<target name="clean" description="Cleanup after build">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <delete file="${emma.runtime.file"/>
    <delete file="${any.other.file.that.needs.to.be.deleted"/>
</target>
```

If you're an [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) user it's a good idea to create an additional target that purges the download cache:

```
<target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
    <ivy:cleancache/>
</target>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for the response. But even though I tried with many permutations and combinations things are not working out. The problem is with the file name. Because of this filename "${instr.dir.out}"  created , I am clueless as how can I delete. Also I am wondering how this file has been created.

Comment: @karthik339 AHHHH now I understand. Look into your ANT code and you'll discover that there is a task configured to create a file using the ANT property ${instr.dir.out}. Your issue is that this ANT property has no assigned value, which explains why the task creates a file using the literal string "${instr.dir.out}". Fairly common problem.

Comment: @Mike,sure will check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

@Mike , I got the solution.The problem was with respect to the directory name that I had give. I created a directory with name outinstr_ (_ was a space) and then I actually assigned  for dir instr.dir.out  ,value = "outinstr" , and here was the fun part ..the value "outinstr" did not had space in it :)... Thanks for helping Mike.... much appreciated